# Submanifold separates the manifold

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-topology, differential

I believe that if we delete the small neighbourhood of a submanifold with codimension more than 2 from the ambient manifold, it won’t separate the manifold. Is there any topological argument I can use? Like proving $H_0=0$ ? Maybe this is not true in general, a counter example will be good.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "the small neighborhood"?

Comment: @ Paul Frost, That's a good point. Let's say closed manifold $M$ is isometrically embedded in closed manifold $(N,g)$. I think by "small" I mean small distance induced by the metric.

Comment: It should be **a** small neighborhood, not **the** small neighborhood. Then the assertion indeed holds and follows from the Poincare-Lefschetz duality. One, however, needs to  be clear on the definition of a submanifold: Say, a smooth submanifold or a tame submanifold in the topological category.

Comment: You should edit your question to make precise what you mean. In your comment you indicate that you consider a closed manifold $M$ isometrically emdedded in a closed manifold $N$ which seems to be endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$. Then probably "small neigborhood" means tubular neighborhood. See https://mathoverflow.net/q/283467.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a topological argument you can use: if $N\subset M$ is a codimension $\geq 2$ submanifold, then it does not locally separate $M$. So you just need to show that $\mathbb{R}^{m}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, for $m\leq n-2$, doesn't separate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I have in mind. But my friend is not convinced by this. So I was thinking about using exact sequence, excision, duality, etc to directly prove that the zeroth homology of complement is $Z$.

Comment: Notice that you are answering the question in the header of the question but not the one in the body of the question (they are genuinely different).